# Set the percentage dimension of two wrapped flexbox elements

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'm exercising about flexbox and I would create a simple layout. But I have some difficulties as can be seen from the code. I want split the content (the two sections in the code) in two parts: 30% and 70%   but the flexbox instruction doesn't accomplish this.  Why? How can I fix it?

[Code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mg0tcah/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flex Layout</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body,html{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            box-sizing:border-box;  
        }

        .container{
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;

        }

        .mainheader{
            flex:100%;
            padding:35px 0;
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(50,180,200);

        }

        nav{
            background-color: black;
            flex:100%;

        }

        ul.navbar{
            list-style:none;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        ul.navbar > li{

            float:left;
            text-align:center;
        }

        ul.navbar  a:hover{
            color:black;
            background-color:white;
        }

        .navbar a{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
            color:white;
            padding:15px;
            font-size:large;
        }



            .side{
            flex:30%;
            padding:10px;
            border:thin solid black;
        }

        .content{
            flex:70%;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <header class="mainheader">
            <h1>My Website</h1>
            <p>With a flexible layout</p>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <section class="side">
            <header>
                <h1>About me</h1>
            </header>
            <h4>
                Photo of me
            </h4>

        </section>

        <section class="content">
        Lorem ipsum
        </section>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a very very stupid mistake concerning the margins-paddings-borders. These when the dimension is in percentage are addicted to width, thus the second part of the layout wraps. To prevent this you have to use :

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

but I'm a knob and I put this property inside html,body tags instead than the "*" selector:

This is the fix:

```
*{
      box-sizing:border-box;

 }
```